# C++ Function signature that returns a PPL task?

Tags: c++, task, ppl, clx

I am a total noob when it comes to using PPL tasks within the C++ environment, so I am having a hard time to figure out what would be the C++ syntax of the following C# code:

```
private static async Task<RandomAccessStreamReference> GetImageStreamRef()
{
    return RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(await GetImageStream());
}

private static async Task<IRandomAccessStream> GetImageStream()
{
    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.BmpEncoderId, stream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8, BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore, width, height, 96, 96, imageBytes);
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
    return stream;
}
```

This C# code was taken from the [Windows Store reversi Microsoft sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj712230.aspx). The best I could get so far is this:

```
Concurrency::task<IRandomAccessStream^> GetImageStream()
{
    auto stream = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    task<BitmapEncoder^>(BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder::JpegEncoderId, Stream)).then([this, stream, width, height, imageBytes](BitmapEncoder^ encoder)
    {
        encoder->SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat::Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode::Ignore, width, height, 96.0, 96.0, imageBytes);
        return encoder->FlushAsync();
    }).then([this, stream]()
    {
        return stream; //Does this even make sense?
    });
    //return stream; //Not sure if I should have this here?
}
```

But it generates the following compile error:

```
error C4716: 'GetImageStream' : must return a value
```

I understand why this error happens, but I have no clue how I can have a function that returns a task without having a return value at two different locations? I haven't even tackled GetImageStream yet.

I am not even sure I took the right path into this...

Thank you!

Comment: Are you compiling the above code as C++/CLI code or plain C++ code? It's not going to work as plain C++ code as the caret signatures for garbage collected reference types are a C++/CLI extension.

Comment: @TimoGeusch: it's not C++/CLI, it's C++/CX: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/162168/what-are-c-cx-and-c-cli-and-how-do-they-relate-to-c-and-winrt

Comment: @TimoGeusch Yes I am compiling as C++/CX. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're real close.  A key point you might be missing is that `then` returns you **a new task**.  So the last `then` in the chain determines the type of your task.

```
auto t = task<int>([] { return 0; });
// t is task<int>

auto t = task<int>([] { return 0; })
.then([](int i) { return 3.14; });
// t is task<double>

auto t = task<int>([] { return 0; })
.then([](int i) { return 3.14; })
.then([](double d) { return "foo"; });
// t is task<const char*>
```

If you just glance at the first line, it looks like you've always got a `task<int>`, but as you can see that's not necessarily the case if you immediately call `then` on it.

Secondly, keep in mind that your function is returning a `task`, not the stream itself.
Usually you'd have the last `then` in your chain return you the task that you'll return from your function, and rather than store the task in a local variable, you just return it.  For example:

```
task<const char*>
get_foo()
{
    return task<int>([] { return 0; })
    .then([](int i) { return 3.14; })
    .then([](double d) { return "foo"; });
}
```

Again, it looks a tad strange because a quick glance makes you think that you're returning a `task<int>`.  This is nicely handled by using `create_task` rather than calling the task constructor explicitly.  It frees you from having to explicitly specify the task's type at all.  Additionally, it's easily changed to `create_async` if you instead want to return an `IAsyncInfo` derivative.

I'm not at all familiar with `BitmapEncoder`, but here's a tweaked version of your code that might do the trick:

```
Concurrency::task<IRandomAccessStream^> GetImageStream()
{
    auto stream = ref new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    return create_task(BitmapEncoder::CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder::JpegEncoderId, stream))
    .then([this, width, height, imageBytes](BitmapEncoder^ encoder)
    {
        // are width, height, and imageBytes member variables?
        // if so, you should only need to capture them OR "this", not both
        encoder->SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat::Rgba8, BitmapAlphaMode::Ignore, width, height, 96.0, 96.0, imageBytes);
        return encoder->FlushAsync();
    }).then([stream]()
    {
        // this should work fine since "stream" is a ref-counted variable
        // this lambda will keep a reference alive until it uses it
        return stream;
    });
}
```

The only real change is using `create_task` and immediately returning its result.

I'm still learning PPL myself, but one thing I've learned that's held up so far is that you should pretty much always be doing **something** with any task you create.  The usual thing to do is use `then` to turn it into a new/different task, but you still need to do something with the task returned by the last `then`.  Oftentimes you just return it, as above.  Sometimes you'll add it to a container of tasks which are then grouped together with `when_all` or `when_any`.  Sometimes you'll just call `get()` on it yourself to wait for its result.  But the point is that if you create a task and don't do anything with it, then there's probably something wrong.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was extremely insightful! In fact, I was able to make it all work now! :)

Comment: One last detail, the function GetImageStream should return a InMemoryRandomAccessStream^ instead of a IRandomAccessStream^ otherwise you get a compile error.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got it working!  One minor point on your answer (which I can't seem to comment on directly): you only get the exception you mention from `.get()` when you call it **on the UI thread**.  This is WinRT's way of not letting you stall the UI to wait for a long-running operation.  If you're in a background thread, though, you can call `.get()` as necessary.

Comment: Another minor comment on the code in your answer: you may want to use `catch (...)` to catch all exceptions, not just those that derive from `std::exception`.  You can re-throw the same exception from such a catch block by just using `throw;` with no argument.

Answer (score 0):

Also if anyone cares, here is how to implement the GetImageStreamRef mentioned above, in C++ version:

```
task<RandomAccessStreamReference^> GetImageStreamRef()
{
    return GetImageStream().then([](IRandomAccessStream^ pStream)
    {
        return RandomAccessStreamReference::CreateFromStream(pStream);
    });
}
```

Also, make sure to NEVER use .get() on any of those tasks, otherwise you will get an exception thrown saying "Illegal to wait on a task in a Windows Runtime STA". The proper way to get the value of this image stream reference is, for example on a DataRequestHandler that sets a bitmap data on the DataRequest:

```
void OnBitmapRequested(DataProviderRequest^ request)
{
    auto Deferral = request->GetDeferral();
    GetImageStreamRef().then([Deferral, request](RandomAccessStreamReference^ pStreamRef)
    {
        try
        {
            request->SetData(pStreamRef);
            Deferral->Complete();
        }
        catch( std::exception ex )
        {
            Deferral->Complete();
            throw ex;   //Propagate the exception up again
        }
    });
}
```